# How to execute nodejs modules in Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, node-inspector

I'm looking for a smart way to run nodejs modules directly in Chrome's developers tools section..
I mean nothing more than the nodejs REPL but within the chrome's dev-tools environment.
Possibly using DevTools' Workspace folders,
maybe integrated with some library or some extension that allows run a nodejs repl session proxyed inside chrome
Any suggestion?
.. To clarify i'm not talking about a browser bundler or module dependency framework like browserify or ResquireJs.
I'd like to test nodejs code while developing, and the chrome devtools' environment is great for debug & inspect ..
thanks!

Comment: check out node-inspector if you're just interested in a debugger, doesn't really do anything you're asking exactly but does let you run a debugger for node on chrome.

Comment: @JakeSellers : thanks, yes i know node-inspector .. that's great for debugging a working app, i was looking for a tool for code hacking with chrome's devtools features. anyway now i'm trying to use it with an ad-hoc module designed to mimic the features i need..

Answer (score 1):

well, node-inspector can be used in a non-standard way:

```
$ node-inspector  --save-live-edit &  
Node Inspector v0.7.1  
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.  
$ node --debug  
debugger listening on port 5858  
>
```

here starts node repl, and on the browser you can require from pwd, live-edit and test code.
the only tricky thing is that on node-inspector page it is needed to set the debugger on "pause" to take the advantage of the console inspection.
have fun!